# Put nested Tab navigator header in parent Drawer Header

Tags: react-native, navigation

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Bottom tabs are 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
2. When the user presses 'a' they will be taken to the 'a' screen, and the header will read 'a'
3. The Drawer navigator will be present (And will be on every single screen)
4. The same should apply to every other page 'b', 'c', 'd'

The problem is with #2, I'm passing my Tab navigator to the Drawer screen (named '0'). So the header will always read the parent (drawer) screen name '0', and not the children.

The only way I got everything working, is I reverse the design...and Tab navigators will be the parent, and each screen in the tab navigator will call a Drawer Navigator, the problem is that I will need to create 4 different Drawer Navigators to do this.

**App.js**

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Arbitrary" component={DrawerScreen}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

**DrawerScreen.js**

```
const DrawerScreen = () => {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigation>
            <Drawer.Screen name='0' component={TabsScreen}/>
        </Drawer.Navigation>
    )
}
```

**TabsScreen.js**

```
const TabsScreen = () => {
    return (
        <Tabs.Navigation>
            <Tabs.Screen name='a' component={a}/>
            <Tabs.Screen name='b' component={b}/>
            <Tabs.Screen name='c' component={c}/>
            <Tabs.Screen name='d' component={d}/>
        </Tabs.Navigation>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that achieves your desired navigation structure:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    // Your home screen content here
  );
};

const aScreen = () => {
  return (
    // Screen 'a' content here
  );
};

const bScreen = () => {
  return (
    // Screen 'b' content here
  );
};

const cScreen = () => {
  return (
    // Screen 'c' content here
  );
};

const dScreen = () => {
  return (
    // Screen 'd' content here
  );
};

const TabsScreen = () => {
  return (
    <Tabs.Navigator>
      <Tabs.Screen name='a' component={aScreen} />
      <Tabs.Screen name='b' component={bScreen} />
      <Tabs.Screen name='c' component={cScreen} />
      <Tabs.Screen name='d' component={dScreen} />
    </Tabs.Navigator>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='Tabs' component={TabsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In this structure, the Drawer navigator contains two screens: 'Home' and 'Tabs'. 'Home' displays the content you want for the drawer, and 'Tabs' contains the bottom tab navigator with screens 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd'. The header will reflect the active tab name as you navigate between them.

Comment: The nested tab header will update its header title, but the parent header will still display 'Tabs'. Another thing I'm considering is If I can somehow get the drawer icon into the child header, then I can just simply hide the parent header and it'd be problem solved.